# New Button on Lookup Search Layout

Tags: opportunity, lookup, contact, button, search-layout

On my Opportunity object I have a look up to Primary Contact. I would to enable users to create a New contact when using the lookup. I would like to have a 'New' Button next to 'Search' search layout. I cannot see where this is possible. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're asking to add a new button to the actual lookup window.

The only way (without writing code) is to enable the Quick Create function in 
*Setup > Customize > User Interface > Enable Quick Create*

There are some big problems with that feature however - doesn't enforce validation rules, can't edit the form, can't control object by object (all or nothing).

Check out the [excellent post by Jeff Douglas](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2011/08/12/roll-your-own-salesforce-lookup-popup-window/) on a possible workaround.